# Is it possible to create an ios app which is just a webview displaying a website?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I need to create an app which will display a responsive website in ios. Only thing my app does will be just to display the website. The user will need to login on website. User should be able to navigate just like he uses a regular web browser. Only thing we need is an icon to start the web application, we dont want our users write the whole url everytime they want to use the app. Any ideas if it is possible or not and if it is possible any examples?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but i don't think apple will accept it

Comment: All the answers that I have seen are right. It's a potty no one states the whole answer, but you already have it there, if you "sum up" the answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), section 2 : Functionality

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make a native app with only a webview, but apple will reject it. Instead, you should create a web application in safari. Just follow this guide:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Answer (score 0):

it's possible but i would say it's not the way to be a iOS application and Apple may reject and not consider this as a application because its not really a native app.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is to start the web application and don't want your users write the whole url everytime they want to use the app, you can use a shortcut from safari which is added to the springboard. The user only needs to write the whole url only the first time.